# OWIN ReadAsAync does not return

Tags: owin, asp.net-web-api2

I have a solution with a WebAPI and a Test Winforms app.  I am trying to access the Wepapi from the Winform.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/serialnumbers");
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
 {
     var x = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<SerialNumber>(); //This does not return
     button1.Text = snlist[0].ComputerName;

 }
```

The client.GetAsync call can be followed to the server and I see it in the Get then the StatusCode is OK and the ReadAsSync gets called but I don't know where it goes on the server and it does not return.

I am able to browse to the /api/serialnumbers url and get data.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

snlist = response.Content.ReadAsAsync>().Result;

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a call to `Wait` or `Result` further up your call stack. This will cause a [deadlock that I describe on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

The proper solution is to remove every call to `Wait` or `Result` with `await`.